# strlen of NULL in c

Tags: c, string, char, realloc, strlen

kind of asking again,
I've asked to make a big string from small ones.
between every small string I need to add '@'
and between every word in every small string I need to add '#'
without any spaces in the start and the end of the new string

I have two questions

1. how should I define the big string in the "main" to avoid unnecessary spaces and not failing the strlen by inserting NULL
2. whats the right way to define the newLenght ? because I keep getting minus numbers.

```
void add(char** addTo, char* str,int on)
{
    //on ==1 for nun last string to add
    if (str != NULL) {
        while (str != NULL)
        {
            char* temp = strtok(str, " \n\0");
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                int newlength = (strlen(*addTo) + strlen(temp) + 3) * sizeof(char);
                *addTo = (char*)realloc(*addTo, newlength);
                strcat(*addTo, temp);
                if (str != NULL)
                    strcat(*addTo, "#");
            }
        }
        if(on)
            strcat(*addTo, "@");
        else
            *addTo = (char*)realloc(*addTo, strlen(*addTo)-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: for me `NULL` is a pointer... if I'm speaking about the zero string terminator I prefer to use `'\0'` explicitly to avoid confusions (for others and for myself).

Comment: `NULL` is *not* an empty string, it's not even a string. `""` is

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the function modifies the contents of the array pointed to by `str`. This side effect might have unforeseen consequences and will cause undefined behavior if `str` points to a string literal.
- `str` is not modified in the loop causing an infinite loop if it points to a non empty non blank string.
- there is no need for the `on` argument. The `@` should be inserted before every small string except the first one, which can be tested via `*addTo`.
- you do not test for reallocation failure.

Here is a modified version that uses `<ctype.h>` to test all white space characters and calls `realloc` a single time per call:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void add(char **addTo, const char *str, int on) {
    int len, newlen = 0;
    unsigned char c, lastc, first;
    char *dest;
    const char *p;

    for (p = str, lastc = ' ', first = 1; (c = *p++) != '\0'; lastc = c) {
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            if (isspace(lastc) && !first)
                newlen++;
            first = 0;
            newlen++;
        }
    }

    if (newlen == 0)
        return;

    if (*addTo && **addTo) {
        len = strlen(*addTo);
        newlen++;
    }

    dest = realloc(*addTo, len + newlen + 1);
    if (!dest) {
        perror("reallocation failure");
        abort();
    }
    *addTo = dest;
    if (len) {
        dest += len;
        *dest++ = '@';
    }
    for (p = str, lastc = ' ', first = 1; (c = *p++) != '\0'; lastc = c) {
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            if (isspace(lastc) && !first)
                *dest++ = '#';
            first = 0;
            *dest++ = c;
        }
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```